# Div heights not the same after setting equal heights with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two divs which I would like to be of equal length. Div1 has text in it which determines its height. Div2 is a scroll box which should have apparent height the same as div1. The following code

```
    <script>
    var div1Height = ((document.getElementById('div1').offsetHeight) + 'px');
    document.getElementById('div2').style.height = div1Height;
    </script>
```

makes div2 have almost the same height as div1, but not exactly. I suspected that there is some padding or margin applied after the script is run, but after removing all of these, the two heights still did not match. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Show the HTML please

Comment: can you provide the markup and css?

Comment: Did you try `box-sizing: border-box`?

Comment: Without seeing the code it's impossible to tell what's wrong, but if you have a border in your `div`s, it might affect. Try setting `box-sizing: border-box`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using two different way of measuring heights. In div1 yo use **offsetHeight** and in div2 you use **style.height**.

Change

```
var div1Height = ((document.getElementById('div1').offsetHeight) + 'px');
```

to

```
var div1Height = ((document.getElementById('div1').style.height) + 'px');
```

Then you would have the same values because you're using the same way of measuring.

Note that you have set style="height:[x] px;" on the div1 for this to work, because style.height retrieves (height) information from the style-attribute of the element.

I don't know why you are doing this in javascript. You maybe have your reasons, but pure css would almost certainly work as well (depending on what you want to achieve of course)